# When i try to install package on raspibitz I receive the annoying warnings regarding locale. What can i do to fix that problem?

Tags: linux, installation, raspberry-pi

When i try to install package on raspibitz I receive the annoying warnings regarding locale.

```
₿ sudo apt install apt-transport-https                                                                                                                                      
...                                                                                                                                                                         
apt-listchanges: Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!                                                                                                                                          
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.                                                                                                                                                                              
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:                                                                                                                                                             
        LANGUAGE = (unset),                                                                                                                                                                                        
        LC_ALL = (unset),                                                                                                                                                                                          
        LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                                   
        LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                               
        LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                                
        LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                              
        LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                                   
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                            
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                         
        LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                                
        LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",                                                                                                                                                                                  
        LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"                                                                                                                                                                                       
    are supported and installed on your system.                                                                                                                                                                    
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_GB.UTF-8").                                                                                                                                                  
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                             
...
```

What can i do to fix that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as root and selected additionally de_DE.UTF-8 to fix the problem.

[Problem of Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269159/problem-of-cant-set-locale-make-sure-lc-and-lang-are-correct?newreg=2a4354494d1b4094a5e74c33cc273f77)